# New command: Arithmetic-based image width

Tags: macros, floats, variable, arithmetic

Theoretically, I think this command should create an environment which is slightly wider than the image it is meant to house:

```
\newcommand{\ListedFig}[3]{
    \piccaption{\small #1} \parpic(#2cm,0pt){\includegraphics[width=#2.5cm]{#3.png}}}
```

But when compiled the image does not seem to have a border of blank space around it. Is this a conceptual error on my part, or a problem with parpic?
Thanks!

My attempt at a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\newcommand{\play}[3]{
    \piccaption{\small #1} \parpic[o]{\includegraphics[width=#2.5cm]{#3.png}}}
\begin{document}

\ListedFig{Caption text}{5}{gull}
\lipsum[1-2]



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Where are `\parpic` and `\piccaption` defined?

Comment: Its an obscure package I found which functions roughly like wrapfig but without the problems associated with wrapfig (I really tried to use wrapfig in this document but could not overcome its limitations....) The documentation can be found here: [link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/picins)

Comment: Please, make a complete example showing the issue.

Comment: Using `\small` inside the argument of `\piccaption` seems wrong, imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't read German. But the following works.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{picins,graphicx,pict2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\ListedFig}[3]{%
  \piccaption{\small #1}%
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=#2cm]{#3}}%
  \parpic(\dimexpr\wd0+0.5cm,\dimexpr\ht0+0.5cm)[o]{\includegraphics[width=#2cm]{#3.png}}%
}


\begin{document}

\ListedFig{Caption text}{5}{example-image}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]